# CAML Query to get only items from SharePoint Library

Tags: sharepoint-server, caml-query, caml

I have a large document library with folders, I'd like having all the items except the folders.
for now, i use this where columns is a list of all internal name from the list

```
CamlQuery q = CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery(10000, columns.ToArray());
```

Then, I'd like having items inside a certain folder but it throws me an exception

```
q.FolderServerRelativeUrl = "/Library/Folder/";
```

Comment: see if this help: http://shlok-sharepoint.blogspot.com/2013/07/caml-query-to-get-all-documents-from.html

Comment: thanks but i'm in client side so i use CamlQuery

Comment: What is the exception you get?